# How can I match a pipe character followed by whitespace and another pipe?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to find all matches in a string that begins with `| |`.

I have tried: `if ($line =~ m/^\\\|\s\\\|/)` which didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should provide more context if this didn't work.

Comment: Or write a different question :)

Answer (score 29):

You are escaping the pipe one time too many, effectively escaping the backslash instead.

```
print "YES!" if ($line =~ m/^\|\s\|/);
```

Answer (score 6):

Pipe character should be escaped with a single backslash in a Perl regex.  (Perl regexes are a bit different from POSIX regexes.  If you're using this in, say, grep, things would be a bit different.)  If you're specifically looking for a space between them, then use an unescaped space.  They're perfectly acceptable in a Perl regex.  Here's a brief test program:

```
my @lines = <DATA>;

for (@lines) {
    print if /^\| \|/;
}

__DATA__  
| | Good - space  
|| Bad - no space  
|   | Bad - tab  
 | | Bad - beginning space  
        Bad - no bars
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's a literal string you're searching for, you don't need a regular expression.

```
my $search_for = '| |';
my $search_in = whatever();
if ( substr( $search_in, 0, length $search_for ) eq $search_for ) {
    print "found '$search_for' at start of string.\n";
}
```

Or it might be clearer to do this:

```
my $search_for = '| |';
my $search_in = whatever();
if ( 0 == index( $search_in, $search_for ) ) {
    print "found '$search_for' at start of string.\n";
}
```

You might also want to look at [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) when you want to use a literal in a regexp.

Comment: Your solution only works if the whitespace is a space character. It fails when it is any other whitespace, such as a tab character.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ^ and the double back-slashes. The ^ forces the string to be at the beginning of the string. Since you're looking for all matches in one string, that's probably not what you want.

```
m/\|\s\|/
```

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
m/^\|\s*\|/
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that before, but it doesn't seem to return a match. This is what brought me to trying the double backslash. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The \s* will match zero or more whitespace characters when, according to the question, he wants to match exactly one whitespace character.